# How can I deploy a shopware PWA app at plesk?

Tags: nuxt.js, plesk, shopware

I want to host a Shopware PWA app at Plesk. For this I have the following index.js and server.js files.

However, I only get the standard page from Nuxt.JS and not the shop.

index.js

```js
require("@babel/register")({});
module.exports = require('./server.js');
```

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');

const config = require('./nuxt.config.js');

// Create new express app
const app = express();

// Listen to port 3000 or PORT env if provided
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Enable production mode
config.dev = false;

// Create instance of nuxt
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
// Add nuxt middleware
app.use(nuxt.render);

new Builder(nuxt).build();
```

My Plesk config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you build the app beforehand?
Did you try to follow the deployment guide from the docs?
https://shopware-pwa-docs.vuestorefront.io/landing/operations/deployment/#guides

I think you currently don't really have a running node server, because you don't start the app with `yarn start`

Comment: This should probably be a comment.